# How to make a diagram for a dashboard in CRM 2011 which includes two or even more entities?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, fetchxml

I'm interested in dashboard CRM 2011. 
It seems that in order to make it nice to view for users We have to create a specific workflows or FormXML or FetchXML.

I wonder, for instance,  to make a diagram for а dashboard IN CRM 2011 which includes two entityes (accounts and contacs, or whatever)?

I guess it could be possible by using FetchXML, however I didn't find any article about that issue.

I know that I make a diagram for accounts and contacts separately and export them in a XML files, so I think there is a way to union the both in one diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific FetchXml for charts\diagrams so you can search examples of reports using FetchXml in reports. One way to obtain a FetchXml is doing a Advanced Find and download the FetchXml. To join to entities you need use  node.
Check some articles that have examples of FetchXml:

- http://www.pedroinnecco.com/2011/09/dynamics-crm-creating-a-radar-chart/
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328117.aspx

Comment: what do you mean by node? I've found such line Microsoft Dynamics supports a new attribute on the link-entity node called visible. Setting visible to false will hide the linked entity in the advanced find user interface. It will still participate in the execution of the query and will return the appropriate results. Did you tell me about that?

Comment: XmlNode called <link-entity .../> is for doing a join between two entities. See the examples.

Comment: As I've understood <link-entity .../> provides possibility to make some filters based on another entity. however, I think that, it's impossiple to create a common diagramm that will show all accounts and contacts by using that way